# Не могу запустить handler в библиотеке aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Есть бот , в боте есть кнопка cancel, вот пример с выводом кнопки

```
await message.answer("Введите тестовые данные", reply_markup=cancel)
```

Вот сам handler

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains="GoToMain", state=None)
async def go_back_to_main(call, state):
    await call.answer(cache_time=10)
    await state.finish()
    await back(call, state)
```

Вот кнопка

```
cancel = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard=[
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="На Главную", callback_data="train:GoToMain:1")
        ]
    ]
)
```

handler на эту кнопку почему то не вызывается, что делать?

Comment: попробуй использовать вместо state=None state='*'

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!